# I wanted to make game welcome screen and here's the code

Tags: python

```
def welcome():
playerx = int(SCREENWIDTH/5)
playery = int(SCREENHEIGHT-200)
messagex = 0
messagey = 0
basex = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            return
        else:
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['background'],(0,0))
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['player'], (playerx,playery))
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['message'], (messagex,messagey))
            SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['base'], (basex,GROUNDY))
            pygame.display.update()
            FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

It gives the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:/Users/AThakur/Desktop/PYTHON PROJECTS/Chrome Dinosaur
> Game/main.py", line 64, in 
> welcome()   File "c:/Users/AThakur/Desktop/PYTHON PROJECTS/Chrome Dinosaur Game/main.py", line 32, in welcome
> SCREEN.blit(GAME_SPRITES['background'],(0,0)) TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not tuple

Comment: Traceback says that `GAME_SPRITES['background'] ` is not a Surface but tuple. Please show us all the code of your game, i can't say anything about this code for now

Answer (score 0):

try 0 instead of (0, 0). I think this would solve the error.